# How to configure a convolution network that maps sentences to a label?

Tags: deeplearning4j

I'd like to train a model which maps a sentence to a label (e.g. "Canon EOS 77D DSLR Camera" maps to a label "Digital Camera").

I understand that strings need to be converted to a vector first. I found an [example of word2vec](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/nlp/word2vec/Word2VecRawTextExample.java) which does this.

I then found a separate [example on how to build a convolution network](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/convolution/mnist/MnistClassifier.java).

That said, I don't understand how to put it all together. Given:

1. A text file containing: `sentence,label`
2. A word2vec trained against all sentences, labels

How do I parse the text file into vectors (taken from word2vec) and pass it into a convolution network for training?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

1. Convert sentences, labels to vectors using `Word2Vec`: [[example](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/nlp/word2vec/Word2VecRawTextExample.java)]
2. Use `CnnSentenceDataSetIterator` to feed training/test data into a convolution network using the aforementioned `Word2Vec`: [[example](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/convolution/sentenceclassification/CnnSentenceClassificationExample.java)]

There is also [an example using ParagraphVectorsClassifier](https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/examples/nlp/paragraphvectors/ParagraphVectorsClassifierExample.java#L92) that does this without a convolution network.